# unable to acces admin panel in django

Tags: python, django

i am creating a todo application using django, but while redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ i get error

> 'module' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'todolist.apps.TodolistConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

the traceback i am getting is:

```
File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  393.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  174.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in get_context_data
  121.         context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_context_data
  93.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  45.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

File "/home/knight/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in __init__
  179.         if self.fields['username'].label is None:
```

Comment: This does not seems to be the full error traceback. Please copy the error traceback from your terminal and post it here

Comment: you gonna help?

Comment: There is something wrong with accessing some dictionary object in your code. Are you sure you're posting all the error trace?

Comment: yes, copied everything as it is!

Comment: you gonna help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done! just changed some of the functions and updated django 1.11.2 to 1.11.4, now works great!